# Store cmd Find result to a variable

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to store the count result from `find /c /i` to a variable

```
find /c /i "sa0" "C:\Users\Luigi.Elsa-PC\Desktop\XBR\Raw\SA00292.01"
```

This outputs `---------- C:\USERS\LUIGI.ELSA-PC\DESKTOP\XBR\RAW\SA00292.01: 2`

I want the number 2 in a variable.

I've tried using `for do`

```
C:\Users\Luigi.Elsa-PC\Desktop>for /F %i in ('find /c /i "sa0" "C:\Users\Luigi.E
lsa-PC\Desktop\XBR\Raw\SA00292.01"') do (echo %i )

C:\Users\Luigi.Elsa-PC\Desktop>(echo ---------- )
----------
```

But as you can see. It's only getting the ---------- not the 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the count only, not the complete line, you have to split it at a suitable delimiter. Splitting at `:` gives you two tokens, you need the second one:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %i in ('find /c /i "sa0" "C:\Users\Luigi.Elsa-PC\Desktop\XBR\Raw\SA00292.01"') do set /a count=%i
echo %count%
```

for use in a batchfile, write `%%i` instead of `%i` (both times)

Standard-Token is `1`, standard delimiters are `<space>`,`<tab>`,`,`,`;`, so your code gives you the first token delimited with standard delimiters, resulting in `----------`.

Comment: the 2 sometimes return a different number. the 2 in this statement is the number of times it found the said string.

Comment: not sure, if I understand, what you mean. `tokens=2` means "take the second token of the output of `find /c ...`"  (the part after the colon, which is the number of lines, which contain your searchstring)

Answer (score 0):

Add `"tokens=*"` parameter in `For` command

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('find /c /i "sa0" "C:\Users\Luigi.Elsa-PC\Desktop\XBR\Raw\SA00292.01"') do (set var=echo %i)
set var=%var:~-1!%)
```